# BLE on Windows 8.1+

Tags: windows, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

Have anyone managed to interface with BLE peripherals on Windows? Is there any library/API that can be used? Qt has now support for BLE in several platforms except Windows (http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtbluetooth-index.html) and unfortunately I'm not aware of an alternative for it.

Comment: What do you exactly mean by BLE peripherals ?

Comment: Do you want to communicate you PC/Laptop with other BLE peripherals ?

Comment: Yes. I want to communicate with my PC/laptop running Windows 8.1 with a Bluetooth Low Energy device (peripheral role). I can handle that on Linux (using Qt that uses BlueZ stack behind the scenes). But I can't find any library for Windows.

Answer (score -1):

You can find the API released by Microsoft for BLE in this link:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/hh450825(v=vs.85).aspx

Be aware that the main drawback of using BLE for Windows 8.1 is that you have to establish a connection with your peripheral device manually in Bluetooth Options for Windows 8.1. You cannot implement a scanning functionality in your application.

Comment: That's bad. Hope this will be implemented on Windows 10 (being able to scan devices on your own application).